# calling google composer (airflow) dag using google cloud function

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-auth

I am trying to call composer dag using API call from cloud function. I am able to call this DAG using rest api using my user and `access token`. which shows that API is enabled and proper authentication is enabled.

However, when I am trying with service account I am getting `Error 401 (Unauthorized)!!1` error.

Following is my code:

```py
def dag_run(url, method='GET', **kwargs):
    google_open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), "https://xxx-dot-us-east1.composer.googleusercontent.com")
    print(google_open_id_connect_token)
    resp = requests.request(
      method, url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
    if resp.status_code == 403:
      raise Exception('Service account does not have permission to access the IAP-protected application.')
    elif resp.status_code != 200:
      raise Exception('Bad response from application: {!r} / {!r} / {!r}'.format(resp.status_code, resp.headers, resp.text))


dag_run("https://xxxx-dot-us-east1.composer.googleusercontent.com/api/v1/dags")
```

service account associated with cloud functions has `composer administrator` role. I know only `user` role is required but it wasn't working and so I changed it.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it’s a permission error with your service account. You can check this two things:

1.The email of the service account must contain less than 64 characters. Because in Airflow tables the field email has a maximum 64 character(character varying(64)) You can see this [link](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-database#:%7E:text=public.ab_user_role-,public.ab_user,-Table%20Structure%3A).

2.Via Cloud Console you can add the user manually, using this commands:

```
gcloud composer environments run <instance-name> --location=<location> users -- create --use-random-password --username "accounts.google.com:<service_accounts_uid>" --role Op --email  <service-account-username>@<...>.iam.gserviceaccount.com -f Service -l Account
```

You can use this commands to list all the users:

```
gcloud composer environments run <env_name> --location=<env_loc> users -- list
```